# PHP string split after specified characters

Tags: php

I have this string: galery/1_**abc def**_**120**.jpg

how do I get:

$description = "**abc def**";  // characters between first underscore _ and second underscore _

$price = **120**; // numbers between second underscore _ and dot .

I think about preg_split but i have no idea how to use it

Comment: See php explode() documentation: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$pizza  = "piece1_piece2_piece3";
$pieces = explode("_", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

In your case:

```
$url = "galery/1_abc def_120.jpg";
$pieces = explode("_", $url);
echo $pieces[0]; //galery/1
echo $pieces[1]; //abc def
echo $pieces[2]; //120.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match function:

```
$string = 'galery/1_abc def_120.jpg';

if (preg_match('/_([^_]*)_([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)/', $string, $matches)) {
   $description = $matches[1];
   $price = $matches[2];
   echo $description . ' ' . $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$str = "1_abc def_120.jpg";  // Your String

$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/',"", $str);  // Remove The File Extension

$divstr = explode("_", $withoutExt); 


echo $divstr[1];   //File NAME 

echo "<br>";

echo $price = substr($withoutExt, -3); // Price

?>
```